# Self-sizing UITableViewCell with UITableView inside it - self-sizing doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having trouble with the new concept of self-sizing cells. They work great for simple custom cells, however, I am trying to have a UITableView inside one of my custom UITableViewCells. I thought I had set up everything correctly, the UITableView inside the cell has constraints and everything and the delegates and datasources are connected as well. What's happening is that 'numberOfRowsInSection' in ChecklistTableViewCell gets called and returns 5, but not the corresponding cellForRowAtIndexPath. Therefore, the cell that should include another UITableView is only shown as a smaller cell with no content.

My 'research' via Google has told me that cellForRowAtIndexPath might not get called because the space for the cells is too small. So, I set the rowHeight of all cells to some constant and the UITableView inside the cell is displayed - but I loose the self-sizing functionality.

Therefore, my question, do self-sizing cells not work with more complex components within custom cells or am I missing something basic or important?

First, the code of my UIViewController:

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *elements;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500.0;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

#pragma mark - UITableView methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Element *element = self.elements[indexPath.row];
    if (something) {
        ...
    } else if (something else) {
        ChecklistTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[ChecklistTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        }
        cell.checklist = element.checklist;
        return cell;
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.elements count];
}

@end
```

Here is my code for the cell that has a UITableView inside of it:

```
@interface ChecklistTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *checklistTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *checklist;

@end


#import "ChecklistTableViewCell.h"

@implementation ChecklistTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Setup table view (self-sizing cells!)
    self.checklistTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0;
    self.checklistTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

#pragma mark - UITableView methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ChecklistElementTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"someIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ChecklistElementTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"someIdentifier"];
    }
    cell.checklistElementTitleLabel.text = self.checklist[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.checklist count];
}

@end
```

And the code for the UIChecklistElementTableViewCell (there's no 'special' code in the .m file):

```
@interface ChecklistElementTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *checklistElementTitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet M13Checkbox *checkbox;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I went with implementing

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

where I return the calculated height for the cell with the table view in it and for all other cells, I return UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

It's not what I had hoped for, but it works. If anyone has another solution, I'm still very interested.

Comment: I've run into this same problem and this seems to be the only solution I've found too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you set correctly you Autolayout's constraints for the cell's elements?
Did you set all the UILabel's line numbers to 0?

Comment: Hi Rem's, I just added trailing/leading/bottom/top space to superview = 0 for the tableview inside the cell which looks fine when taking away the self-sizing functionality.